# Access files on Linux mint VirtualBox guest

Tags: linux, virtualbox

I have a Linux virtualbox that I use for development. The stuff I'd like to share to the host operating system resides in /var/www. I tried setting up a samba share, but I can't seem to see my virtualbox on the network. Does anyone know how I'd go about doing this? I searched, but the only thing I've found is virtualbox's shared folders which isn't quite what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default VirtualBox networking defaults to an internal NAT implementation, which only allows the guest to access the network and not the other way around.

To access the guest from the host you have to use a different [networking mode](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html#networkingmodes).

My preferred solution is host-only networking, because the guest appears as a proper networked-machine on the host, without being exposed to the public network.

Bridged networking would also do, but you'd have to secure the guest as if it was a separate machine and there may be networks where having two MAC addresses for a single physical PC is not advised or even allowed.

Why aren't shared folders what you are looking for, anyway?

Comment: Shared folders go the "wrong way." I want to access one folder in one place on my vbox. I might be misunderstanding shared folders, but it didn't seem like what I wanted.

Comment: @Josh: True, the shared folder storage resides on the host. But on Linux guests you can mount them wherever you want like any other filesystem. I actually prefer them to be stored on the host, since that way they can be shared among guests and they are safe if I decide to just delete a VM or something.